# How to update time of time interval according to increase number of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the function where i wanna updated value from array in time of time interval function

```
       var itemNumber = 0;
        function startAnimation() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#' + ItemIdArray[itemNumber]).show(ItemAnimArray[itemNumber]);
                itemNumber = itemNumber + 1;
            }, ItemAnimSecArray[itemNumber]);
        };
```

how can i update this timer of timeinterval function according to increament in itemNumber variable for array.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will be better for you need by calling startAnimation in the setTimeout :

```
    var itemNumber = 0;
    function startAnimation() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#' + ItemIdArray[itemNumber]).show(ItemAnimArray[itemNumber]);
            itemNumber = itemNumber + 1;
            startAnimation();
        }, ItemAnimSecArray[itemNumber]);
    };
```

Check this fiddle to check how it works : http://jsfiddle.net/Finrod/HLvqn/

Comment: how to reset it with new value

Comment: I have edited my answer to use setTimeout, it should do what you want